# Image preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I am attempting to make a an image pre loader. There is an array of low res images and an array of high res images. I create a new image object and run through a loop to preload these images. I then use a line of Jquery to set the background to use a low resolution image until the high resolution object has loaded, and when that loads I use another line of Jquery to switch the background to use this high resolution image.

The problem I am having is that the code skips the low resolution background setting and loads the high res image.

Here is the code:

```
// Low res image array
    var lowres = ["image1lr.jpg", "image2lr.jpg", "image3lr.jpg", "image4lr.jpg"];  

// Full res image array
    var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];      


// Low res image path
    var lowresimagepath = "url(images/rotate-background/low_res/";
// Full res image path
    var imagepath = "url(images/rotate-background/";

// Counter
    var i = 0;  

// Image preloading
       for(i=0; i<=images.length; i++) 
       {
           // Create object
           imageObj = new Image(); 

           imageObj.src = imagepath + images[i] + ')';
       }

//Generate random number
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);    

//Set background image to random low res image
    $(".bg_home").css({'background-image': lowresimagepath +lowres[rannum]+')'});       

//Once image objects are loaded switch to high res image 
     imageObj.onLoad= function(){ 
                          $(".bg_home").css({'background-image': imagepath + images[rannum] + ')'});    
                      }
```

Comment: imageObj.src = imagepath + images[i] + ')'; I am not sure it is just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was a mistake in my code. I have fixed it though I still have the same problem.

(I've edited my post to reflect this)

Comment: on last line you must wrap your code inside a function  `imageObj.onLoad = function(){......}`

Comment: and your random number generation has problem. remove the brackets around floor method. `var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);`

Comment: And about your loop you must use `for(i=0; i<images.length; i++)` using literal 3 is not right.

Comment: and also you must instantiate an `Image` object for every image, so move `new Image()` inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience image.onLoad isn't very reliable. There are different cases where it doesn't work, e.g. IE or cached images.

I'd take a look at https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded 
I've used that library and it works great.

As for your code, it seems to be rather invalid:

```
// Low res image array
var lowres = ["image1lr.jpg", "image2lr.jpg", "image3lr.jpg", "image4lr.jpg"];  

// Full res image array
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];      


// Low res image path
var lowresimagepath = "images/rotate-background/low_res/";
// Full res image path
var imagepath = "images/rotate-background/";

//Generate random number
var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);      

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imagepath + images[i];

    if(i == rannum) {

        //Set background image to random low res image
        $(".bg_home").css({'background-image': 'url(' + lowresimagepath +lowres[i]+')'});       

        //Once image objects are loaded switch to high res image 
        iamge.onLoad= function() { 
                $(".bg_home").css({'background-image': 'url(' + imagepath + images[i] + ')'});   
        };

    }

}
```

**That's working under the assumption that your idea is to have a a single random image added to your background, while all images are loaded in the background.**

Comment: I've tried this. it doesn't seem to switch to the high res images (i fixed your misspelling of image.onload when i tried it)though it does seem to be preloading.

Comment: Any errors? Does image.onLoad even fire? Add a console.log or something into the function to see if its fired. If it's not, try the plugin I recommended.

Comment: The onload doesn't seem to be firing, looks like i'll be using that plugin, thanks for the effort and the link.

Answer (score 0):

The Image objects' src is a css property. It should just be the URL

```
imageObj.src = imagepath + images[i] + ')'; //Generates "url('whatever');"
//It can't be that, must just be the path.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code has lots of problems, here is a clean version I've made, but its not tested.

```
(function(){ // prevents name conflicting with other scripts 

    var BASE_PATH_LOW_RES = "images/rotate-background/low_res/",
        BASE_PATH_HIGH_RES = "images/rotate-background/"; // since these are constants its better to use capitalized letters

    var lastLoadedIndex = 0, // you must ensure all images are loaded and its hard to preload them in parallel
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length),
        images = [
            {low: "image1lr.jpg", high: "image1.jpg"},
            {low: "image2lr.jpg", high: "image2.jpg"},
            {low: "image3lr.jpg", high: "image3.jpg"},
            {low: "image4lr.jpg", high: "image4.jpg"}
        ];

    var onComplete = function() {
        $(".bg_home").css({'background-image': 'url(' + BASE_PATH_HIGH_RES + images[randomIndex] + ')'});
    }

    var loadNext = function(){
        if(lastLoadedIndex == images.length) { // all images has been preloaded
            onComplete();
        } else {
            var imgTemp = new Image();
                imgTemp.src = BASE_PATH_HIGH_RES + images[lastLoadedIndex++].high;
                imgTemp.onLoad = loadNext;
        }
    }

    $(".bg_home")
        .css({'background-image': 'url(' + BASE_PATH_LOW_RES + images[randomIndex].low + ')'});       

    loadNext(); // start to preload every image one after another
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, the .onload seems to be the issue so i'll be using the plugin suggested by another poster. Though I have learned a lot from this post so thanks.